# probability formula binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Recently doing probability course I've came across this formulae. Can anyone explain what is means?

$ (p^k * q^{N-k}) * N! \mid k!(N-k)!  $

So far I came to know

p - is probability than an event occurs

q - probability than an outcome won't occur.

I just need to know what N and k means here in the equation.

Comment: The probability a person has brown hair is p. Now pick N people independently (not family members etc). What is the probability that k of those people have brown hair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your typesetting needs work.

$\dfrac{p^k q^{N-k} N!}{k!~(N-k)!}$ is the probability for $k$ successes among $N$ independent Bernouli trials with identical success rate $p$ (and failure rate $q:=1-p$); for any $k\in\{0..N\}$.

More often writen as $\binom Nk p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$.

$p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$ measures the probability for an arrangement of $k$ success and $N-k$ failures. $\binom Nk$ counts the distinct permutations of such an arrangement.

This is the probability mass function  for a Binomially distributied random variable.

---

$p$ is the success rate.

$q$ is the failure rate, $q:=1-p$.

$N$ is the amount of iid Bernouli trials.

$k$ is the amount of successes among the favoured event.

When $X$ is a Binomial random variable with parameters $N, p$, then:

$$\mathsf P(X=k)= \dbinom{N}{k}p^k q^{N-k}~\mathbf 1_{k\in\Bbb N:0\leq k\leq N}$$

Example: When $X$ is the count for snake-eyes among five fair die, $N=5, p=1/6, q=5/6$, the probability for obtaining 3 snake-eyes is:.$$\mathsf P(X=3)=\dfrac{5!~5^{2}}{3!~2!~6^5}$$

Comment: Can you please give a small example to help understand better what it means ?

Comment: Here's your example: flip a coin 7 times. What is the probability of getting exactly 4 heads? Determine $N, k,  p$ from this.

Comment: Here N is 7, p is  4/7 and k =4 am I right?

Comment: No. $p$ is the probability of one success.

Comment: So p would be 0.5?

Comment: @user2475 For an unbiased coin, yes.